# .js Block TCP established connections browser plugin

Tags: javascript, browser, tcp, analytics

1. I can create app [over Safari:](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UsingExtensionBuilder/UsingExtensionBuilder.html)
2. I can include script to load before page loads.
   Something like [this](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.TCP__analytics.ashx):

```js
# start collection for one subnet only.
 when CLIENT_ACCEPTED {
     if [IP::addr [IP::client_addr]/8 equals 10.0.0.0] {
         TCP::analytics disable
     }
 }
 when HTTP_REQUEST {
     # must check subnet again to avoid starting for all
     # connections
     if [IP::addr [IP::client_addr]/8 equals 10.0.0.0] {
         # make stats queryable by URI
         TCP::analytics key "[HTTP::uri]"
     }
 }
```

3. **I want to block TCP established connections to be blocked due to analytics.** What .js codes are possibilities?
   https://www.shivarweb.com/2977/what-does-google-analytics-do/
4. I'd also like to **block SSL SEND** from happening and **block 3rd-party cookies**. Code suggestions?
5. Is it possible to include your own **robots.txt** so there would be no way for analytics to follow? Into browser plugin code. Safari/Chrome/Firefox etc.

Comment: Best here I could do on macOS was changing values of TCP Keepalive.<br>
<br>
Before:<br>
sysctl -A | grep net.inet.tcp.*keep<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepinit: 75000<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt: 8<br>
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive: 1<br>
<br>
After:<br>
sysctl -A | grep net.inet.tcp.*keep<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 3000<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 500<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepinit: 700<br>
net.inet.tcp.keepcnt: 1<br>
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive: 1<br>
<br>
Commands:<br>
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.keepidle=3000<br>